# Run a Video from Gallery Using Android VideoView

Tags: android, uri, android-videoview

I am trying to select video from Gallery. The selected video url is like this below url which I am trying to show in the VideoView

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20200711_165727.mp4
```

The problem is when I try to add this Uri to VideoView  `mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri)`, it doesn't work and do nothing. Is it the problem with URI or I have to do any otherway. Could anyone help me?

Comment: look at [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-training-video-view/index.html?index=..%2F..advanced-android-training#2)

Comment: The example is using video from raw file nto from gallery.